# What is the meaning: splash about and splash around?

Tags: idioms

I'm reading “Alice in Wonderland” and found some idiom "splashing about in the pool", but cannot understand why is used about preposition. In the Internet I have found "splash around" and became more confused.

> The children splashed about in the pool. 
>   They splashed around for an hour.

Comment: Because "about" is used in a similar manner to "around," especially in British English.  Google "splashing about" in quotes, and you'll get mostly British sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "about" conveys a more broad range of movement... "splashing in a pool" could mean that you're just sitting there, quietly clapping your hands into the water and thus disturbing the surface. On the other hand, "splashing about" suggests that you're moving around the pool while splashing, so carries the image of more vigorous play, probably more boisterous and generally noisy as well.

The use of "around" would carry a similar meaning, although we'd probably "*play around*" but "*splash about*".

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/splash+about